# Copmute the norm of $n$-th iteration of a weighted shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory

Consider the operator $L :\ell^2 \to \ell^2$ defined by $$Lx=\left( 0, \frac{x_1}{a_1},\frac{x_2}{a_2},...\right)$$ where $a_n$ is some positive increasing sequense such that $\lim_{n\to \infty } a_n \to +\infty$, find $\| L^n \|_2$.

My solution, we have $$L^2x=\left( 0,0, \frac{x_1}{a_1a_2},\frac{x_2}{a_2a_3},...\right)$$
$$\dots$$
$$L^nx=\left( 0,..., \frac{x_1}{a_1a_2..a_n},\frac{x_2}{a_2a_3...a_{n+1}},...\right).$$
So we have $$\| L^nx \|_2^2 =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \left( \frac{x_i}{a_ia_2..a_{n+i-1}} \right)^2 \leq \frac{1}{(a_1a_2..a_n)^2} \|x\|_2^2$$
Now if $e_1=(1,0,...)$ then $$\| L\|_2=\|L\| \| e_1\| =\| Le_1 \|= \frac{1}{a_1a_2..a_n}.$$
Hence $\| L^n \|_2=\frac{1}{a_1a_2..a_n}$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: In my opinion it is correct. There are misprints in the third line from below: there should be $L^n$ instead of $L.$ Also the operator norm should be denoted $\|\cdot \|,$ not $\|\cdot\|_2.$ You are using both notations, which is misleading.

Comment: Depends on how you define copmute?

Comment: A silent policeman ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc :-)